# Why django-unicorn doesnt update hmtl-collection?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

There is **`django-unicorn 0.44.0`**'s component configuration.

`refresh.py`

```
from django.db import connection
from django_unicorn.components import UnicornView
from datamarket.models import Clients


class RefreshView(UnicornView):
    clients = None
    count = None

    def get_client(self):
        self.count = Clients.objects.all().count()
        self.clients = Clients.objects.all().order_by("surname")[:10]

    def az(self):
        self.clients = Clients.objects.all().order_by("surname")[:10]

    def za(self):
        self.clients = Clients.objects.all().order_by("-surname")[:10]

    def mount(self):
        self.clients = Clients.objects.all().order_by("surname")[:10]
        self.count = Clients.objects.all().count()
```

`refresh.html`

```
    <div>
         <button class="btn" unicorn:click="get_client()">Update</button>
         <button class="btn" unicorn:click="az()">A-Z</button>
         <button class="btn" unicorn:click="za()">Z-A</button>
         <p> Total {{ count }} records</p>
     </div>

   <table>
                <thead>
                    <th>Surname</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for c in clients %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ c.surname }}</td>
                        <td>{{ c.name }} </td>
                        <td>{{ c.age }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% empty %}
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">No found</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>

   </table>
```

The `mount()` function doing well when I refresh page, it changes `clients` value in html. Also `count` value updating well too when I call `get_clients()` by button.
But it doesnt change client collection in table when I call `get_clients()`, `az()`, `za()` by button. Why?

It's worked literally week ago and now I dont get any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solve is that `refresh.html` **need one general `<div>`**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).